# SSR + RESTful API с помощью django-rest-framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Я делаю web-приложение на `Django`.

Решил, что  буду использовать `SSR` и `RESTful API` одновременно.
На данный момент для `SSR` я использую обычные `Django`-представления, а для `API` - `django-rest-framework`

Но это неудобно. Я пишу одно и то же 2 раза.

Вопрос, примерно, следующий:

> Могу ли я получить контекст и отрендерить страницу (шаблоны), используя `django-rest-framework`?

*Примечание:*
*Без использования `Js` со стороны клиента (то есть, не `SPA`). `Content-Type: text/html;`.*

Если да, то как именно? На что следует обратить внимание?
Если нет, то можно ли частично использовать `django-rest-framework` для получения информации внутри `Django`-представления, чтобы передать её в шаблон?

*Представление `DRF`:*

```py
class PostViewSet(LikedMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = (
        IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
        IsAuthorOrReadOnly,
    )

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
```

*`Django`-представление:*

```py
class PostsView(View):
    @staticmethod
    def get(request):
        context = {
            'posts': Post.objects.all(),
            # Не хочу снова писать тут "Post.objects.all()", как в представлении выше.
            # Контекста может быть гораздо больше, к тому же в некоторых шаблонах
            # может потребоваться дублирование сразу нескольких DRF представлений.
            #
            # Я хочу как-то вызвать DRF представление и получить его ответ,
            # который сюда вставлю.
        }

        return render(request, 'core/posts/index.html', context)
```

Comment: С помощью джанго-шаблонизатора можно рендерить любой текст, в совершенно любом месте вашего кода, это не привязано к представлениям.

Comment: @МистерФикс Ну да, можно... Но причём тут это? Вопрос о том, что у `django-rest-framework` свои классы представлений, основанные на `serializers` и другой внутренней логике. Собственно, я не понимаю, как можно ими воспользоваться для получения информации в `Django`-представлениях (или любом другом месте) для `SSR`.

Comment: вопрос-то был про возможность рендеринга. Ну рендерьте, в классах drf, никто не мешает. Это можно делать. Как вы полученный текст отправлять собираетесь на клиент, это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: @МистерФикс А как рендерить в классах `DRF`? Я об этом и спрашиваю. Расскажите, пожалуйста, подробнее, если Вам не сложно. С отправкой клиенту я сам разберусь, это действительно другой вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

До DRF пока руки не дошли, ковыряю внутренности Django.
Но отправлять из DRF HTML можно.

Самый хороший и простой вариант - это использования HTMLMixin, представленный ниже.

Более продвинутый и сложный - это реализация адаптера (также ниже пример). Хоть и не знаю, насколько это оправдано создавать велосипед по отношению к HTMLMixin, который использует стандартные возможности DRF по генерации HTML. Но если вы планируете переиспользовать контроллеры внутри контроллеров (для использования в одном шаблоне сразу нескольких DRF), то вам всё равно потребуется какой-нибудь `строитель` или `адаптер`

Примеры и подробности ниже. Интересно, какое решение выберите для множественного переиспользования DRF ;)

## Генерация HTML в DRF

Вам нужно лишь поменять настройку класса `APIView`, от которого вы косвено отнаследовались через `ModelViewSet`:

`renderer_classes`

Для поддержки стандартного поведения и с html можно реализовать это так

```
class PostViewSet(LikedMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = (
        IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
        IsAuthorOrReadOnly,
    )
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
    
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
    
class PostViewSetHTML(PostViewSet):
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'core/posts/index.html'
```

Для простоты использования можно сделать динамическую генерацию `PostViewSetHTML` для всех DRF

```
# to make html only classmethod
class classproperty(object):
    
    def __init__(self, fget):
        self.fget = fget
    
    def __get__(self, cls, owner):
        return self.fget(owner)

class HTMLMixin:
    
    html_template_name = None
    
    @classproperty
    def html(cls):
        html_class_name = '%sHTML' % cls.__name__
        attrs = {
            'renderer_classes': ['TemplateHTMLRenderer'],
            'template_name': cls.html_template_name,
        }
        new_class = type(html_class_name, (cls,), attrs)
        cls.html = new_class # cache it
        return new_class
    
    

class PostViewSet(HTMLMixin, LikedMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = (
        IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
        IsAuthorOrReadOnly,
    )
    
    html_template_name = 'core/posts/index.html'
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
    
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
```

И использовать его как `PostViewSet.html.as_view()`.

Главным минус является отсутствие возможности переиспользования других DRF с наследованием привилегий и прочих свойств.

## Переиспользование результатов DRF

Первым делом нужно определиться, какой метод отвечает за генерацию нужных вам данных.
Например, для получения списка из модели в DRF используется следующий метод:

`list(request, *args, **kwargs)`

В результате будет объект класса `Response` с полем `data`
Если есть пагинация, то

```
data = OrderedDict([
    ('count', page_paginator_count),
    ('next', next_link),
    ('previous', previous_link),
    ('results', data)
])
```

Если пагинации нет, то получите просто `data` (который в `results`)

Как это выглядит на практике

```
class PostViewSet(LikedMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = (
        IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
        IsAuthorOrReadOnly,
    )
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
    
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)

# пример со множеством drf
class PostsView(View):
    
    success_url = './success.html'
    success_url = './failed.html'
    template_name = 'core/posts/index.html'
    
    # пример get запроса
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        drf1 = PostViewSet(request)
        response1 = drf1.get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        data1 = response1.data
        
        drf2 = AuthorViewSet(request)
        response2 = drf2.get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        data2 = response2.data
        
        context = {
            'posts': data1,
            'authors': data2,
        }

        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
    
    # пример post запроса
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        drf1 = PostViewSet(request)
        try:
            drf1.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)
        except:
            #  - TODO: better exception management
            #  - Обычно в View мы не редиректим, а генерируем заново страницу с указанием ошибки
            # DRF при этом же динамически сообщает об ошибке, без перегенрации страницы
            # В иделе все post запросы оставить полностью на DRF.
            # А это воспринимать лишь в качестве примера использования DRF во View как факт, что это возможно
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.failed_url)
```

Но в этом примере есть и проблема - нет проверки авторизации пользователя и его привилегий. Здесь лишь продемонстрирована идея переиспользования методов drf.

## Создание Адаптера для переиспользования результатов

По-хорошему основная логика обработки данных должна находиться внутри моделей, а контроллеры должны быть как можно проще. А для переиспользования функций DRF (если их берём за основу контроллеров) лучше создать адаптер для стандартных Django View. Ниже накидал пример адаптера с обработкой ошибок, проверкой аутентификации и прав доступа к DRF и возвращением HTML документа. Мой адаптер лишь как пример. Нужно писать хороший, стабильный, который бы учитывал все возможные нюансы работы. В первую очередь доработать обработчик ошибок. В последствии использование адаптера становится очень простым.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from rest_framework import exceptions

def exception_handler(exc, request):
    """
    Returns the response that should be used for any given exception.
    By default we handle the REST framework `APIException`, and also
    Django's built-in `Http404` and `PermissionDenied` exceptions.
    Any unhandled exceptions may return `None`, which will cause a 500 error
    to be raised.
    """
    if isinstance(exc, (Http404, PermissionDenied)):
        raise exc # allow Django to dispatch 404/403 errors in a standart way

    if isinstance(exc, exceptions.APIException):
        
        if getattr(exc, 'auth_header', None):
            from django.contrib.auth import REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME
            from django.contrib.auth.views import redirect_to_login
            return redirect_to_login(
                request.get_full_path(), settings.LOGIN_URL, REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME
            )
        
        if getattr(exc, 'wait', None):
            return render(request, 'retry-after-error.html', {'wait': exc.wait})

        if isinstance(exc.detail, (list, dict)):
            data = exc.detail
        else:
            data = {'detail': exc.detail}

        return render(request, 'detail-error.html', data)

    return None


class DRFAdapterView(View):
    drf_class = None
    template_name = None
    kwarg_name = 'data'
    
    response_class = TemplateResponse
    
    def initial(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.drf = self.drf_class(request)
        self.drf_request = self.drf.initialize_request(request, *args, **kwargs)
        
        self.drf.perform_authentication(self.drf_request)
        self.drf.check_permissions(self.drf_request)
        self.drf.check_throttles(self.drf_request)
    
    
    def handle_exception(self, exc, request):
        """
        Handle any exception that occurs, by returning an appropriate response,
        or re-raising the error.
        """
        if isinstance(exc, (exceptions.NotAuthenticated,
                            exceptions.AuthenticationFailed)):
            # WWW-Authenticate header for 401 responses, else coerce to 403
            auth_header = self.drf.get_authenticate_header(self.drf_request)

            if auth_header:
                exc.auth_header = auth_header

        response = exception_handler(exc, request)

        if response is None:
            self.drf.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
        
        return response
        
    
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.initial(request, *args, **kwargs)
            response = super().dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as exc:
            response = self.handle_exception(exc, request)
        return response
    
    
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = self.drf.get(self.drf_request, *args, **kwargs)
        response.__class__ = self.response_class
        # response.context = response.data # может и так заработает
        response.context = {self.kwarg_name: response.data}
        response._request = request
        response.template_name = self.template_name

        return response

class PostsView(DRFAdapterView):
    drf_class = PostViewSet
    template_name = 'core/posts/index.html'
    kwarg_name = 'posts' # не обязательный аргумент

class AuthorsView(DRFAdapterView):
    drf_class = AuthorViewSet
    template_name = 'core/authors/index.html'
    kwarg_name = 'authors' # не обязательный аргумент
```

Как и динамической генерацией html для DRF через `HTMLMixin` в прошлом примере, можно сделать 1 в 1 с динамической генерацией HTML с использованием View. И использовать как `PostViewSet.html.as_view()`.
Считаю, что подобная реализация адаптера + динамическая генерация вьюшек будет не плохим сочетанием с возможностью подключить множество DRF сразу (только это нужно будет учитывать при написании адаптера, в примере это не учитывается). Но работы в целом тут на дня два найдётся. Представленный код лишь примеры, которые позволяют продемонстрировать возможности интеграции обмена данных между DRF и классическим Django View.

Comment: Спасибо большое за развёрнутый ответ! Обязательно всё попробую и отпишусь до окончания конкурса.

Answer (score -2):

```
from django.template import RequestContext, loader


template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
context = RequestContext(request, {'my_item': "some_item", })
text = template.render(context)
```

Код взял из учебника по джанге. Таким образом можно отрендерить шаблон в совершенно любом месте кода. Ещё можно заглянуть в функцию `render()`, и посмотреть как там обрабатывается текст.

Comment: Простите, но это не то, что я хотел. Я некорректно сформулировал вопрос. Я имел в виду, как получить контекст для этого самого рендеринга в классах `DRF`, то есть как воспользоваться их логикой. Они явно не предоставляют информацию, поэтому я и спрашиваю.

Comment: @nomnoms12, здесь же есть пример получения контекста. В чём вопрос-то?

Comment: Я очень плохо понимаю, куда мне следует добавлять Ваш код. Я обновил вопрос, добавив представления. Подскажите, пожалуйста, буду очень признателен.