# Django django-rest-framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли при помощи DFR render-ить в html не привлекая frontend фраемворки?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1001862/339283. Проверить ответ руки не дошли, но очень похоже на то, что Вам нужно.

Comment: Вот так же есть описание в [офф. документации](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#templatehtmlrenderer)